# What is the best way to empty a char string in C?

Tags: c, string

Hi I have a char string

`name[50] = "I love programming"`

what happen is that I want to empty this string before I call my another function so that I can store something in the same array

will this work?

`name[0] = '\0';`

or is there anyway to empty the string without creating any new function or use any other library?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the array after you "empty" it?

Comment: Well my task is to find the longest word so I already found that in `name` the longest word is programming so I store them in another array called `longest_word` so I want the array to be empty before pulling up another array to find and store that is why I need to know how to empty the array @Staven

Comment: Then you can just use `strncpy(longest_word, name, 49)` (`longest_word` must have a size of at least 49+1 for the \0 byte). `strncpy` doesn't care what data was in `longest_word`, it will just overwrite it, so you don't need to "empty" it in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) instead. This would just nullify the buffer but the memory allocated would any how gets deallocated from stack when the variable goes out of scope.

```
memset (name,'\0',sizeof(name));
```

Comment: Why prefer this to "name[0] = '\0';"? You're trading constant time for linear.

Answer (score 6):

Setting first char to nul is perfectly acceptable. But if that string was sensitive in terms of security, then you should zero it out with `memset`.

Edit:

Answer from Matteo Italia made me dig a bit deeper on this subject. According to [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1381.pdf) (and Matteos answer) `memset` could be optimized away, and so is not the best option to remove sensitive information from memory. The document has several options, but none of them is portable and reliable, so it proposes new function standard `memset_s` just for such purposes. This function does not exist yet, so we're currently stuck with non-portable (`SecureZeroMemory`), non-reliable (`volatile` trick), or non-optimal options (`secure_memset` example).

Answer (score 3):

There's really no concept of emptying a char string in C. It's simply a pointer that points to some allocated memory. You can reuse that memory in any way you wish, without "emptying" it first. So, the easiest way to empty it is "just don't".

If you want to explicitly clear all contents of the string for some reason, use the `memset` approach given in other answers.

If you want to "empty" it in the sense that when it's printed, nothing will be printed, then yes, just set the first char to `\0'.

---

To conclude, it all depends on what you **really** want to do. **Why** do you want to "empty" the string?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you might use memset this way:

```
char * myString;
...
size_t len = strlen(myString)
memset (myString, 0,len);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tehnically it is correct, for example:

```
char array[10] = "hello";
printf("%d\r\n", strlen(array)); // prints 5
array[0] = '\0';
printf("%d\r\n", strlen(array)); // prints 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
memset(name, 0, 50);
```

or

```
bzero(name, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends from the effect you want to obtain. If you just want to zero its length you can do, as you said:

```
*name='\0';
```

If, instead, you want to clean your string from sensitive data, you should zero it completely with `memset` (some operating systems also have a "secure" zeroing function that should be guaranteed not to be optimized away by the compiler - see e.g. [SecureZeroMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows).

On the other hand, if the function you are calling just uses the buffer you are passing as an output buffer disregarding its content, you may just leave the buffer as it is.